# overloading operator<< for set

Tags: c++, vector, set, operator-overloading

I have a set of pairs of integers and I want to print it, so I overloaded << operator for set and pair classes as :

```
template<typename T, typename U>
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, pair<T,U> &p){
    os<<"("<<p.first<<","<<p.second<<")";
    return os;
}


template<typename T>
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, set<T> &s){
    os<<"{";
    for(auto it = s.begin() ; it != s.end() ; it++){
        if(it != s.begin())
            os<<",";
        os<<*it;
    }
    os<<"}";
    return os;
}
```

When I create a set and output it like

```
set<pair<int,int>> s;
cout<<s<<endl;
```

It gives the errors :

```
cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
   os<<*it;
```

and

```
initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = std::pair<int, int>]’
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

I don't know what is the problem, the errors are very cryptic. Moreover, if I create a set of integers and print it, it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of `it` in `auto it = s.begin()` is a `const_iterator`([source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin)).  as such when you call `os<<*it;` you need a function that can take a `const`
 pair.  If you change you code to this it will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename U>
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<T,U> &p){
    os<<"("<<p.first<<","<<p.second<<")";
    return os;
}


template<typename T>
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const set<T> &s){
    os<<"{";
    for(auto it = s.begin() ; it != s.end() ; it++){
        if(it != s.begin())
            os<<",";
        os<<*it;
    }
    os<<"}";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    set<pair<int,int>> s {{1,2}};
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/290f2f016e22c878)

I would also suggest that you always take the second parameter as a `const &` for

1. You can bind a temporary to a `const &` (ex function returns)
2. You should not be modifying the container during output so this uses the C++ type system to enforce that.

Comment: Thanks, actually, when I wrote this for vector (instead of set), it worked, that's why I got confused.

Answer (score 2):

The stream operators are not meant to modify the value their are passed. Hence, you should accept a const reference instead of a mutable reference:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const pair<T,U> &p){
    os<<"("<<p.first<<","<<p.second<<")";
    return os;
}


template<typename T>
inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const set<T> &s){
    os<<"{";
    for(auto it = s.begin() ; it != s.end() ; it++){
        if(it != s.begin())
            os<<",";
        os<<*it;
    }
    os<<"}";
    return os;
}
```